# Кодировка, Java, NetBeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans, utf-8

Учусь ява для веб. Написал сокет для общения с клиентом все работает но с проблемой такой что при запуске программы прямо в ide то работает отлично но если я собираю и самостоятельно запускаю джар файл то теряется кодировка. Пробавал и с командный строки открывать, во всех местах где можно (на клиенте тоже) менял строки в нужную кодировку. Даже классам (файлам) менял кадировку ничего не помогает. С базой данных все в норме не изза нее. Пробовал в eclipse переносить то там так же. Может кто знает по опыту изза чего это. Сам я уже мучаюсь наверно дня три минимум и сам проблему решить не могу.

Comment: При чём здесь Андроид? И в чём конкретно проявляется "потеря кодировки"? Указывайте кодировку явно при конвертации байтов в строки и обратно. По умолчанию используется кодировка системы или переданная при запуске параметром `-Dfile.encoding=whatever`

Comment: @woesss андроид потому что клиент у меня на андроид. Указываю кодировку как то вот так: String data = new String (data.getBytes ("utf8")); Вроде бы по умолчанию ибо я ничего не менял. А как это может изменить?

Comment: Если вы работаете в Windows, то, скорее всего, у вас в Netbeans исходники в кодировке CP1251. Нужно в свойствах проекта установить кодировку исходников.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov проверил вроде utf8

Comment: `String data = new String (data.getBytes ("utf8"))` - это что за бред? Строка из строки? Указывать кодировку нужно при записи строки в поток, или оборачивать поток в [`OutputStreamWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String-), с указанием кодировки. И при чтении из потока аналогично. На Андроиде можно не извращаться - там по-умолчанию "UTF-8".

Comment: @woesss щас почитаю больше об этом. Я только учусь не суди строго